# Android : How to clip views by parent, like CSS overflow:hidden

Tags: java, android, css, xml, android-view

I have views as follows :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/global_legal_gap"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:background="@drawable/post_sound_bg"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/post_sound_card_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/post_sound_card_height">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/album_art"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/post_sound_card_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/post_sound_card_height"
            fresco:backgroundImage="@drawable/music_placeholder" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/play_icon_control"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="3dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout>
```

As shown in the parent `RelativeLayout`, I'm using `android:clipToPadding="true"` and 
        `android:clipChildren="true"`, yet the children of this parent view are still protruding outside it.

Or I'm I doing this right? How do I achieve something like CSS's `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Have you tried adjustViewBounds = "true"?

Comment: @harshjain ` adjustViewBounds` is for Images, and beside, it's not even for this, but aspect ratio.

Comment: there is no `android:clipToPadding` in the code. Could you post a sketch of what you would like?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić the code was simply cut out by poorly formatted code, see edit.

Comment: Have you tried setting android:layout_height to `match_parent`?

Comment: @TadijaBagarić ok, tried that, not changing.

Comment: yo! I didn't understand one stuff: you said that the relativelayout has the clipToPadding, but it is in the linearLayout, right? another stuff is: which view is overflowing from its parent? the child relativelayout?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley, the SimpleDraweeView.

Comment: @Relm thanks, can you provide a screenshot of the actual result? just to have a correct idea of what is appening :)

Answer (score 11):

Consider changing layouts. What you want can be done with `ConstraintLayout`.

Just set the the dimensions of the layout and don't set the constraint on the part you want to overflow/hide.

The following code shows a `View` that adjusts it dimensions to its constraint and another that overflows.

[image]

Create a new android project and paste this as `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="55dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="84dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I'd love if this can be done with what I posted above. I want to understand why this isn't working before changing anything.

Answer (score 4):

Your parent view has

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

which means that the view takes all available width and up to all available height if child views are large enough. With this setup you can't seethe `overflow:hidden` behaviour because the parent will resize itself to contain children up to the whole screen size.

Actually, default view behaviour in android is similar to `overflow:hidden`.

What you need to do to see it is set fixed dimentions on the parent.

Just try to use something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
```

and you'll get the idea.

On a different note, you don't need to have a LinearLayout just to host a RelayiveLayout - use the RelativeLayout directly. Also, using `android:orientation="horizontal"` makes it behave similarly to flexbox direction row, not sure if that's something you want here.

Answer (score 0):

In native Android, `overflow: hidden` is `android:clipToOutline="true"`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).